# Can (Dal) Segno and (Dal) Segno Segno appear on the same bar?

Tags: notation, musical-forms, repeats

This is a follow-up question to my previous [question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/132527/how-to-notate-two-nested-repeat-loops-and-that-finish-on-the-same-repe).

I have made a transcription using Guitar Pro 8 of a song with the following structure:

`Intro, A, B, A, B, A, Coda`

Guitar Pro 8 outputs and plays audio according to what is written on the sheet. After creating the score on my previous [question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/132527/how-to-notate-two-nested-repeat-loops-and-that-finish-on-the-same-repe) for this transcription -- which did not output the intended structure in the output audio playback -- I created the following one, which did output the intended audio playback (the content of the bars was replaced by whole notes for simplicity):

[image]

My idea here was that at the end of the first iteration of the loop, it would pick up the *Dal Segno* and go back to section A for the second iteration. Then on the end of the second iteration it would pick up the *D.S.S al Coda* and go back to section A for the third iteration. Then it would reach the *Da Coda* at the end of section A and jump directly to the Coda.

This solution worked as desired when playing the output audio, but this seems very ambiguous notation to me and it honestly seems yet another case of crazy Guitar Pro behavior.

1. Is it allowed to put combinations of *Segno*, *Segno Segno*, *Coda* and *Double Coda*) on the same bar (like in bar 3)?
2. Is it allowed to put combinations of *D.S. (al Coda/Fine/Double Coda)* and *D.S.S. (al Coda/Fine/Double Coda)* on the same bar (like in bar 15)?
3. Assuming that the answer to the two previous questions is *yes*, then how is it decided which navigation symbol on bar 3 to jump to first in this example? Is it always the one that does not have *al Coda* appended to the correspoding *Da Segno / Da Segno Segno / Da Capo* on bar 15?
4. Is the score that I presented above valid for this case?

---

I found some very informative posts about nested repeats and their mixed usage with Segno/Coda navigation marks, but none of them refer to this specific case. The posts I read are:

- [Dal Segno al Coda and repeats in Guitar Pro](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/118263/dal-segno-al-coda-and-repeats-in-guitar-pro). This last one really confirms what I already suspected, which is that Guitar Pro makes its own assumptions when navigation marks such as Da Segno/Da Coda are mixed with repeat signs and sometimes the playback of the audio is unexpected when compared to the sheet.
- [Are there established good practices for how to use musical navigation markers correctly?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/70294/are-there-established-good-practices-for-how-to-use-musical-navigation-markers-c)

Comment: Are measures 4 and 5 the same?

Comment: @phoog No, they have different content. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double D.S. is confusing. The first thing the player sees at M.15 is *"D.S.S. al coda"*. They take that and go to the coda, so they never reach the second *D.S.*

See my answer to your [previous question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/132527/how-to-notate-two-nested-repeat-loops-and-that-finish-on-the-same-repe) for a better way to do this.

Comment: @PiedPier I also thought the same. Unfortunately Guitar Pro 8 forces the _D.S.S._ marker to always be on top of the _D.S._ marker. I did manage however to move the _al Coda_ from the _D.S.S._ marker to the _D.S._ marker. So now, bar 15 shows _Dal Segno Segno_ on top and _D.S. al Coda_ below it. Would you say this is this clear and unambiguous?

Comment: Although it makes sense to me, Guitar Pro 8 only plays Intro, A, B, A, Coda after the edit I mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: I am marking this answer as the accepted one because it shows that mixing navigation markers in the same bar can get confusing for some people and also links to the accepted answer with a solution in my [previous question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/132527/how-to-notate-two-nested-repeat-loops-and-that-finish-on-the-same-repe), which is also an answer/solution to this one.

Answer (score 2):

Are you stuck with using Guitar Pro as your notation program?   What you showed us is impossible to sightread.  It could be acceptable as a 'reference guide' to a song where the player has previously had time to work out the geography.

Comment: For the time being I am stuck with Guitar Pro, unfortunately. I also have the Cubase score editor available, but learning it will involve time and a learning curve, as I haven't started using it yet. It might be time to spend some time on that :) Do you recommend any score editor program? I heard a lot about Sibelius and Finale for example.

Comment: Also, indeed this sheet is not meant for sight reading. Instead, it is one of a collection of 15 to 20 transcriptions for one classical guitar of short VGM pieces (around 20 measures each, none longer than 90 s). I was aiming at 1 transcription per page (of 2 sides). Given that these tracks are VGM MIDI sequences that loop infinitely, I don't want to write a sheet as `Intro ||: A B :|| A Coda` because the final A and Coda are artificial (as in they are not in the actual piece, which just loops infinitely). I mostly want to capture the notes + fingerings for guitar in a compact way.

Comment: Why not notate them as looping infinitely then?

Comment: That's actually a good idea, and it'd be more faithful to the original thing

Comment: The 'big boy' notation programs are currently Sibelius, Finale and Dorico.   But they're expensive.  Investigate MuseScore.  It's free, and a big step up from Guitar Pro for general notation (maybe not for strictly guitar-specific stuff?)  Don't be conned by the easily confused MuseScore subscription library.  You just need the free MuseScore notation program.

Answer (score -1):

This should be fine, especially once explained. Bar 15 should have a thin double barline for clarity.

Comment: The missing double barline on bar 15 was a typo, my bad. I didn't realize that the picture did not have it when I posted this question.

Comment: Notation that requires additional explanation always causes problems.